# How to make inside component state to global state?

Tags: reactjs, routes, state, native

I made weather app by react native.
Fetching weather data from accuweather and saved to state.
And I need display state data in child page(page1, 2, 3).

How can i? Please help me.

https://github.com/charian/WhatTheWeather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not provided any particular code I can only assume that you want to pass some props to pages. I have found in your repo this piece:

```
navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
}
```

This function needs to pass props to the page you want to navigate to.

You can do it like this `this.props.navigation.navigate(route, {paramName: this.state.paramName});`

When on that page, you access these props with `this.props.navigation.getParam(paramName, defaultValue)` or `this.props.navigation.state.params`.

Comment: I am try https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html
But in this case, is not it only possible to switch pages?

Comment: On that link you will find 

const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
onPress={() => navigate('Profile', { name: 'Brent' })}

Which is same as this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {name: 'Brent'}). You need to replace name: 'Brent' with your data from weather forecast.

Answer (score 0):

You should send down your state data by props to the other components/pages.

Comment: Sorry, I am not developer.
Can you more detail? like example code.

Comment: Just curious ... How did you manage to build a Weather App in React Native if your're not a developer and know about props in React? =)

Comment: I study from youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1vE7G6YQCc&list=PL7jH19IHhOLNPOI3bEBtSw1Acp3fS0enw

Answer (score 0):

Define your state in constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      experienceId: '',
      desktopDetail: this.props.navigation.state.params,
      clientId: '',
      installedVR: '',
      activeVR: '',
    };
  }
```

Access your variable using `this.state.clientId` anywhere in your component.